# Touchpad issues on HP Pavilion dm4 (can't right click)

Tags: hardware, touchpad, hp, permissions

Can anyone help me with my touchpad issues? I have a HP Pavilion dm4 and it has two areas on the bottom of the touchpad to designate right and left clicks. This mostly doesn't work on Ubuntu in the fact that it recognizes any taps on either tap zone as a left click. Instead, I have it set so if I tap anywhere on the pad it makes a left click.

There should be, and there are, many ways in the mouse configuration window to simulate a right click using only a touchpad. None of these work. Changing mouse orientation doesn't do anything, "dwell click" also does nothing, and, the oddest part of this problem, whenever I try to turn "Simulated Secondary Click" off (it doesn't work anyways, but just to try to toggle it), the entire theme of my desktop changes to a gray Windows '95ey look. The only way to get rid of this is to close and reopen the mouse preferences window.

My computer is fairly new and the Ubuntu installation is less than a day old. I didn't do anything that I think could cause this. The problem is that I can't right click. Help, please?s that I can't right click. Help, please?

Afterword: I installed two scripts from http://sansmicrosoft.blogspot.com/2010/10/pavilion-dm4-1160-erratic-touchpad.html . They didn't do anything I couldn't already do, and they did not make it possible for me to right click. :(

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while and you are probably past this issue by now but this may help someone else.

```
synclient -l
```

will show touchpad config options

```
synclient AreaBottomEdge=3500
```

Allowed the use of the "clicking" part of the touchpad.

You can put it in your rc.local or in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf to enable at every boot.

Answer (score 1):

Enter in terminal

```
synclient -l
```

Then make sure that:

```
RightButtonAreaRight=1
RightButtonAreaBottom=1
```

if not then just run:

```
synclient RightButtonAreaRight=1
synclient RightButtonAreaBottom=1
```

I've been dedicated Ubuntu 12.04 for 4 months and just stumbled across this, up until now I didn't have Right click support.  Hope this helps you.